# Copy contents of network drive to local folder

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ola-hallengren

I have an automated third party backup places files on a network drive.

I've mapped this drive to a local folder on the DB server using the following PowerShell script

```
$pass ="xxxx"|ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential('MERIVALEHOSTED\SVC.APPSQL',$pass)

New-PSDrive -Name K -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Credential $cred -Root '\\10.0.30.113\sqlbackup\ACCCluster01$AccWarehouseAG';
Get-PsDrive;
```

This maps my network drive to the K drive.

I then want to copy the entire folder structure of this (it's the output of Ola Hallengrens backup - DIFF/FULL/LOGS) to a local drive, but not before deleting the current contents of this folder.

This is the first step of a automated DB restore. I've been able to automate the restoration process successfully using the DbaTools powershell module, but the file copy isn't working.

I've tried both:

```
Copy-Item -path K:\*.* -destination M:\VoxtronRestore\;
```

as well as this:

```
function Copy-Directories 
{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $source,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $destination        
    )

    try
    {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Force |
            Where-Object { $_.psIsContainer } |
            ForEach-Object { $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source), $destination } |
            ForEach-Object { $null = New-Item -ItemType Container -Path $_ }

        Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Force |
            Where-Object { -not $_.psIsContainer } |
            Copy-Item -Force -Destination { $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source), $destination }
    }

    catch
    {
        Write-Host "$_"
    }
}

$source = "K:\"
$dest = "M:\VoxtronRestore"

Copy-Directories $source $dest
```

The first of which fails to copy anything, and the second gives me an error about overwriting the source with itself.

I am wondering if anyone has any better suggestions or modifications to the above which will enable this to complete successfully.

Comment: So, quick question about the drive mapping.  Does it happen under the same account that is running either the SQL Agent or the Credential for the Powershell step?  Because the drive mapping is per user and if you ran the create mapping command as one user, it doesn't necessarily exist for any other user on that server.

Comment: The drive mapping uses different credentials as it is outside of our domain. (hence why I had to store the credentials before I run the new psdrive. But, this is all run from the same script under the same user in powershell/sql agent.

Comment: Why not use `Remove-Item` to clean up the directory first (since you said "deleting the current contents of this folder"). Also, instead of using `*.*`, it should rather be `Copy-Item K:\ -Recurse M:\VoxtronRestore\`

Comment: I'll post that as an answer then :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a system administration question, not a DBA question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*.*` will only return the files directly under `K:\` (You probably have a folder with the database/instance name here). Use `Copy-Item K:\ -Recurse M:\VoxtronRestore` instead.